# No WAN connection, but LAN OK

Tags: networking, internet

After the last automatic update internet is down whether I use wifi or ethernet.  I can however connect to router, and Web server on the LAN side. Pinging any Web site fails. I use version 12.0 4. I'm about to download new cd and do fresh install. Any tips to fix my connection before I install new version of Ubuntu?

```
ifconfig
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:21:9b:db:5a:ca
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) Interrupt:17

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1d:e0:50:c8:d1
    inet addr:192.168.1.3 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::21d:e0ff:fe50:c8d1/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:30715 (30.7 KB) TX bytes:23103 (23.1 KB)

netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 wlan0
169.254.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
```

Comment: Please edit your question by adding the output of "ifconfig" and "netstat -nr"

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's a system problem? Maybe a router problem. Can you access the WAN from other devices using the same LAN, or have you tried a ping to any website?

I suppose you've already tried but just in case, you could simply restart the router.

Comment: Router has been restated. All other devices connect to the internet no problem.

Comment: I had a look at your netstat and this line:  0.0.0.0 192.168.1.254 looks weird... 0.0.0.0 usually is the path to default network, meaning the whole WAN, but it's pointing to 192.168.1.254 instead of pointing to the router at 192.168.1.1 Can you try to edit  manually the gateway in your connection manager to change the gateway to .1?

Comment: Router is at 254 intentionally. IPs 1 through 20 are Dhcp assigned automatically.  ih see reverted router to default settings, and still no go. Only Ubuntu laptop is unable to connect to WAN. All LAN devices respond to ping from Ubuntu. Websites do not respond. That is why I'm here asking for help.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more... the only think I can guess it's a ports problem, since you have connection but not browsing capability. Hope somebody with more networking expertise have a look at this, good luck!

Comment: Are you running any firewall software on your Ubuntu system such as ufw or iptables?

Comment: No I'm not using any firewall software